# Shell script change directories, run git branch to find the branch I'm in and then assign the output to a variable

Tags: git, shell

This is more of a shell scripting question than a git problem.

I have a directory structure that is along the lines of:

```
/projects/Project1/package1 
/projects/Project1/package2
/projects/Project1/package3
```

etc...

I am using git for each of my packages but I am trying to run a script that will pull the latest changes from the remote for each of my packages. I currently have a list of the package directories but I would like to:
1 - iterate through each of the package directories
2 - for each package directory get the current branch that I'm in and store it in a variable

I'm currently stuck on step 2 as I'm not sure how I can navigate to the directory, run a 'git branch' command, parse it and then spit the output out into a variable. I can do each of those steps individually but i'm not able to put it together.

This is what I currently have:

```
for pkgName in `ls "$WORKSPACE"/src/`
do
    pkgDir="$WORKSPACE"/src/"$pkgName"
    CURRENT_BRANCH=${cd $pkgDir && `git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e "s/* \(.*\)/\1/"`}
    echo $CURRENT_BRANCH
    #... checkout to mainline, pull, then checkout $CURRENT_BRANCH and rebase mainline...
done
```

Essentially I would like to assign into '$CURRENT_BRANCH' the git branch name of the directory.

Comment: Where does `src` fall in with `/projects/Project1/package1`, etc?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for substituting the output of a command into the line is `$(...)`, not `${...}`. So it should be:

```
CURRENT_BRANCH=$(cd $pkgDir && git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e "s/* \(.*\)/\1/")
```

Answer (score 0):

The common way to get current branch is `git symbolic-ref HEAD` (and string substitution). Because often `HEAD` points to current branch, if we are really on some branch. You can see [this snippet](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/lib/git.zsh#L1-L6) for its expansions.

In total, I would write

```
for pkgDir in "$WORKSPACE"/src/* ; do
  cd "$pkgDir"
  ref=$(command git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null)
  CURRENT_BRANCH=${ref#refs/heads/}
  cd -
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the branch name, if you use `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`, you are done and to not need to filter later.

This works:

```
for pkgName in `ls "$WORKSPACE"/src/`
do
    cd ${WORKSPACE}/src/${pkgName}
    CURRENT_BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
    echo $CURRENT_BRANCH
done
```